# How to use http4s server and client library as a proxy?

Tags: scala, http4s

I want use http4s as proxy(like nginx), how to forward all data from my http4s server to another http server?

What I really want do is append a verify function on every request before do forward function. Hopefully like this:

```
HttpService[IO] {
  case request =>
    val httpClient: Client[IO] = Http1Client[IO]().unsafeRunSync
    if(verifySuccess(request)) { // forward all http data to host2 and
                                 // get a http response.
      val result = httpClient.forward(request, "http://host2")
      result
    } else {
      Forbidden //403
    }
}
```

How to do this with http4s and it's client?
Thanks

#### Updated

with the help of @TheInnerLight, I give it a try with the snippet code:

```
  val httpClient = Http1Client[IO]()

  val service: HttpService[IO] = HttpService[IO] {
    case req =>
      if(true) {
        for {
          client <- httpClient
          newAuthority = req.uri.authority.map(_.copy(host = RegName("scala-lang.org"), port = Some(80)))
          proxiedReq = req.withUri(req.uri.copy(authority = newAuthority))
          response <- client.fetch(proxiedReq)(IO.pure(_))
        } yield response
      } else {
        Forbidden("Some forbidden message...")
      }

  }
```

With a request: `http://localhost:28080`(http4s server listen at 28080):
but occurred a error:

```
[ERROR] org.http4s.client.PoolManager:102 - Error establishing client connection for key RequestKey(Scheme(http),localhost) 
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:252)
    at sun.nio.ch.UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.finish(UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:198)
    at sun.nio.ch.UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.onEvent(UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:213)
    at sun.nio.ch.KQueuePort$EventHandlerTask.run(KQueuePort.java:301)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[ERROR] org.http4s.server.service-errors:88 - Error servicing request: GET / from 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:252)
    at sun.nio.ch.UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.finish(UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:198)
    at sun.nio.ch.UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.onEvent(UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:213)
    at sun.nio.ch.KQueuePort$EventHandlerTask.run(KQueuePort.java:301)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

#### Latest Version

```
 val httpClient: IO[Client[IO]] = Http1Client[IO]()

  override val service: HttpService[IO] = HttpService[IO] {
    case req =>
      val hostName = "scala-lang.org"
      val myPort = 80
      if(true) {
        val newHeaders = {
          val filterHeader = req.headers.filterNot{h =>
            h.name == CaseInsensitiveString("Connection") ||
            h.name == CaseInsensitiveString("Keep-Alive") ||
            h.name == CaseInsensitiveString("Proxy-Authenticate") ||
            h.name == CaseInsensitiveString("Proxy-Authorization") ||
            h.name == CaseInsensitiveString("TE") ||
            h.name == CaseInsensitiveString("Trailer") ||
            h.name == CaseInsensitiveString("Transfer-Encoding") ||
            h.name == CaseInsensitiveString("Upgrade")
          }
          filterHeader.put(Header("host", hostName))
        }

        for {
          client <- httpClient
          newAuthority = req.uri.authority
            .map(_.copy(host = RegName(hostName), port = Some(myPort)))
            .getOrElse( Authority(host = RegName(hostName), port = Some(myPort)))
          proxiedReq = req.withUri(req.uri.copy(authority = Some(newAuthority)))
            .withHeaders(newHeaders)
          response <- client.fetch(proxiedReq)(x => IO.pure(x))
        } yield {
          val rst = response
          rst
        }

      } else {
        Forbidden("Some forbidden message...")
      }

  }
```

It works fine enough for my REST API web server.
There are some error when proxy `scala-lang.org` for test:

```
[ERROR] org.http4s.blaze.pipeline.Stage:226 - Error writing body 
org.http4s.InvalidBodyException: Received premature EOF.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
HttpService[IO] {
  case req =>
    if(verifyRequest(req)) {
      for {
        client <- Http1Client[IO]()
        newHost = "host2"
        newAuthority = Authority(host = RegName("host2"), port = Some(80))
        proxiedReq =
          req.withUri(req.uri.copy(authority = Some(newAuthority)))
           .withHeaders(req.headers.put(Header("host", newHost)))
        response <- client.fetch(proxiedReq)(IO.pure(_))
      } yield response
    } else {
      Forbidden("Some forbidden message...")
    }
}
```

Note that you should definitely avoid littering your code with calls to`unsafeRunSync`.  You should generally be using it at most once in your program (in `Main`).  In other circumstances, you should focus on lifting the effects into the monad you're working in.

Comment: Thanks.It almost what I want.But a error occurred: `Error establishing client connection for key RequestKey(Scheme(http),localhost) ` when I replace `host2` to `scala-lang.org` and give http4s a request.

Comment: Update more detail information at question.Thanks a lot.

Comment: @LoranceChen I think the authority doesn't exist when you connect to localhost so instead of mapping it, you can just create it.  I've edited the above code to take care of it.

Comment: It works good enough. Also has some strange behavior for `scala-lang.org`. Is it not enough implement nginx's simplest `proxy_pass` with just apply a new hostname? Maybe out of topic for the question.

Comment: @LoranceChen Yeah, you probably ought to replace the host headers too using `.withHeaders(proxiedReq.headers.put(Header("host", "host2")))` and strip out the connection headers but it should be enough to get you started.

Comment: Hi, thanks.It become better with the append Headers.but has the error: `[ERROR] org.http4s.blaze.pipeline.Stage:226 - Error writing body ` caused by `org.http4s.InvalidBodyException: Received premature EOF.`.Do you has any idea?I'm not really master at http protocol and I hope do nginx `proxy_pass` like thing.Thanks again~

Comment: @LoranceChen It could be due to a mismatch caused by hop-by-hop headers getting forwarded.  To make it well behaved, you'll need to strip them to.  There is a list of hop by hop headers here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers#hbh

Comment: I will try it tomorrow. It's 01:00 clock now.( ･᷄д･᷅ ), thanks

Comment: also has same error when I proxy for `scala-lang.org`. But work's fine for my simple REST API web server.I will update code

Comment: Note that this solution does not work properly for large response bodies. The proxied connection is closed as soon as `client.fetch(proxiedReq)(IO.pure(_))` completes, and this results in truncated responses to upstream.